# I want to delete models in the wagtail cms

Tags: django, wagtail

I use wagtail CMS and i want to disable the models in the cms. 
I want to use them in the code, but the customer should could only use one of them

Answer (score 1):

If you set `ModelName.is_creatable = False` then the user will not have the option of creating them.